# Kotlin Coroutines for fetching from raw.githubusercontents.com

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-multiplatform

I am currently working on porting a Kotlin library to Kotlin/Js. I am currently struggling with how to fetch something from the web. I want to retrieve a page from raw.githubusercontent.com ([example](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mikeferguson/moveit_python/ros1/CMakeLists.txt)).

My code currently looks like this:

```kotlin
// function
fun getText(url: String): String? {
    val url = "some url"
    var text: String? = null
    GlobalScope.launch {
        text = window.fetch(url).await().body.toString()
    }
    return text
}

//test
@Test
fun run_test() = runTest {
    val text = getText(url)
    assertNotNull(text)
}
```

But I never seem to get the code in the Coroutine executed when running my unit tests. It's my first time working with coroutines, so I am not too familiar with them.

Have a nice day

Comment: Maybe your test is the problem. Can you share your unit test for the above code?

Comment: `launch()` executes asynchronously. You didn't mention what test framework you use, but if it supports coroutines then it probably has some way to get into coroutine context. If not, then it makes more sense to use `runBlocking()` instead of `launch()`: `val text = runBlocking { window.fetch(url).await().body.toString() }`.

Comment: for testing I use karma.
`runBlocking()` is not available in kotin/js

Comment: I think it would be useful to share the code of the unit test itself. You might want to use `kotlinx-coroutines-test` for your tests (it's multiplatform since coroutines 1.6.0)

Comment: I added the test code to the question

Comment: I suggest reading about testing of asynchronous code in this framework, because the problem seems the same no matter if we use Kotlin and coroutines or JS and `window.fetch()`. All my searches for "karma test asynchronous" return results about Jasmine, but I'm not familiar with JS testing frameworks, so I won't be able to help you more.

Answer (score 1):

By using the `GlobalScope` you've broke the structured concurrency. [Try to avoid it](https://elizarov.medium.com/the-reason-to-avoid-globalscope-835337445abc).

Your `window.fetch` just runs in the topmost scope, so your test (`runTest`) doesn't wait for it's completion. It's like a daemon thread.

I would try to rewrite it to something like:

```kotlin
suspend fun getText(url: String): String? {
    val url = "some url"
    val text = window.fetch(url).await().body.toString()

    return text
}

//test
@Test
fun run_test() = runTest {
    val text = getText(url)
    assertNotNull(text)
}
```

---

Well, if it's an interface, it means that you:

- Cannot change the parameters of the method (i.e. pass the scope)
- Cannot make it an extension function (i.e. on the scope)
- Cannot add `suspend` modifier

…

the only solution you probably have is to use `runBlocking`:

```kotlin
fun getText(url: String): String? {
    val url = "some url"
    val text = runBlocking {
        window.fetch(url).await().body.toString()
    }

    return text
}
```

Comment: Since I am implementing an interface in that class that's sadly not possible

Comment: Why didn't you put that into your question? That's important!